# How to index R matrix without it reverting to vector

Tags: r, vector, matrix

I declared a 1 by 6 matrix A by saying:

```
A <- matrix(1:6, nrow=1)
```

I then do dim(A) and as expected I get 1 by 6...but then I do A[,2:5] and I would expect that to be a matrix of dimension 1 by 4 with entries 2,3,4,5...but instead dim( A[,2:5] ) gives me NULL! it degraded into a vector or something. How can I avoid this?

I am ultimately trying to do something like:

```
A[,a:b] %*% X[a:b,a:b] %*% t(A[,a:b])
```

varying a and b so I can multiply only parts of the above matrices together..but this breaks when A decays into a vector...

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `,drop=FALSE` as an additional (trailing) argument to involving `]`.

Example:

```
R> M <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
R> M[,2]                  ## looses matrix class
[1] 3 4
R> M[,2,drop=FALSE]       ## forced to a n x 1 matrix
     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    4
R>
```

This may well be *the* main FAQ, but for compatibility reasons the behaviour is unlikely to change.

Comment: Glad to hear that. And in which case it is common around here to 'accept' the best answer by clicking on the tick mark, and only you as the original poster of the question can do that.

Comment: Circle 8.1.44 of 'The R Inferno' http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf